# When editing an existing file with Vim, will it replace or change that file?

Tags: vim

I've read that most editors will replace the file when you actually want to save changes to that file: [How to execute a command whenever a file changes?](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes#181543)

How does Vim behave?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it might depend on various settings related to '[backup](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#backup)', everything that has to keep a copy of the file as it was before the write happened. one of settings that controls that is: '[backupcopy](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backupcopy)':

> When writing a file and a backup is made, this option tells how it's
>   done.  This is a comma separated list of words.
>
> The main values are:
>
> ```
> "yes"    make a copy of the file and overwrite the original one
> "no"     rename the file and write a new one
> "auto"   one of the previous, what works best
> ```

so, depending on your vimrc (`backup` set and `backupcopy` to `no`), vim might rename a file. when

Comment: Yeah this also complies with my observation that inotifywait printed the same inode number that has changed..

Comment: comment on @math's comment: i changed the answer quite a bit after his comment. the former version stated that the test i did wrote into the same inode / file. but since my vimrc runs without `backup` ... not a valid test :)

Answer (score 1):

I've observed that the option [`writebackup`](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/options.html#%27writebackup%27) and whether the edited file has more than one [hard link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) changes the behavior of Vim in that regard.

The following results pertain to Vim 9.0.2167 and Neovim 0.9.4 on Arch Linux using ext4 when saving a file with `:w`.

## In case `writebackup` is on (which is the default)

- Editing a file with only one hard link to it:

  - inode changes (file is recreated)
  - changes timestamps Access, Modify, Change, and Birth
- Editing file with multiple hard links:

  - inode stays the same
  - hard links stay intact
  - Birth timestamp remains the same. Access, Modify, and Change timestamps do change

## In case `writebackup` is off (`:set nowritebackup`)

- inode stays the same
- only Modify and Change timestamps change. Access and Birth remain the same

See also the [`backup`](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/editing.html#backup) option:

> If you write to an existing file (but do not append) while the 'backup',
> 'writebackup' or 'patchmode' option is on, a backup of the original file is
> made.  The file is either copied or renamed (see 'backupcopy').  After the
> file has been successfully written and when the 'writebackup' option is on and
> the 'backup' option is off, the backup file is deleted.  When the 'patchmode'
> option is on the backup file may be renamed.
>
> ```
> 'backup' 'writebackup'  action
>
> off       off        no backup made
> off       on         backup current file, deleted afterwards (default)
> on        off        delete old backup, backup current file
> on        on         delete old backup, backup current file
> ```