# Tail -f on newly-created files with unknown names

Tags: linux, shell, tail

I have a program that for each run generates a new log file. To watch what's going on, I'd like to `tail -f` the log - only problem is that I don't actually know the file name in advance.

So, is there a way to follow all files that match a certain (shell glob) pattern? I guess I could easily script something like this, but I'm wondering if there's already a solution out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct way to do with with `tail` without knowing the name - if you knew that then `tail --follow=name --retry` would work and it would wait for the file to appear and then start following it.

I'd suggest writing a little shell script that uses `inotifywait` to watch for the file appearing and then starts `tail -f` to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the file name in advance:

1. decide on a filename, like `foo.log`
2. watch that file: `tail -F foo.log` (doesn't matter if foo exists or not)
3. use a tool to watch the directory for file changes and run a command

For the command, either:

- move the new file to overwrite foo.log `mv the_new_file_which_appeared foo.log` (if the app logging opens once, this will work fine)
- or just symlink: `ln -s the_new_file_which_appeared foo.log` - and tail should catch that.

To properly watch the directories (step 3), you need a configurable, clever tool.

Personally, I'd use [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) with the [Guard::Process](https://github.com/guard/guard-process).

In practice, Guard is not much heavier than using shell scripts (it's a thin layer on top of inotify on Linux), and it's all very quick and easy to setup.