# inotify script stops after first change

Tags: linux, bash

Inspired by [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/181543/315715) I have written the following `copy_library.sh` script, saved in the same folder as a file called `library.bib`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e close_write library.bib; do
    cp -f ./library.bib ../other_place/ ;
    echo "Library copied"
done
```

If I start this script manually with `./copy_library.sh` the process exits after the first copy (which works successfully):

```
londonrob ~/mydir
> ./copy_library.sh 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
library.bib CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 
Library copied
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
londonrob ~/mydir
>
```

and no further changes are tracked. I'm sure I'm supposed to do something with this script so it's running continuously "in the background" without me having to start it manually.

But what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `inotifywait` man page:

> inotifywait efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's
>   inotify(7) interface. It is suitable for waiting for changes to files
>   from shell scripts. It can either exit once an event occurs, or
>   continually execute and output events as they occur.

and

> -m, --monitor
>       Instead of exiting after receiving a single event, execute indefinitely. The default behaviour is to exit after the first event
>   occurs.

EDIT: I have a log, which is appended to each 15 seconds. The following script executes the while one loop for each line outputted by inotifyread:

```
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait -e modify /tmp/modem_log.csv -m | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    echo "Copy coperation here..."
done
```

In your case, you have to change the event (modify) to close_write, of course.

Comment: The problem with `-m` is that it just outputs event names to `stdout`. It means that the while loop is never called.

Comment: Can't you open `inofifywait -m`, redirect the output, and then modify the `while` loop just reading lines from `stdin`? (i.e. call `inofifywait` just once) I'll try it later and report.

Comment: Please see EDIT in my answer.