# How to protect Linux from Ransomware by detecting mass changes?

Tags: linux, malware-detection

I wonder if it would be possible to stop running ransomware on a Linux system by detecting mass changes on files. Can [watchdog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) or [entr](http://entrproject.org/) or [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) be used to detect bulk file changes and stop what is going on by a ransomware? Here is a [discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes) regarding file change detection which may help.

Comment: This post belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/