# How do I run a bash script automatically everytime I hit CTRL + S?

Tags: shell-script, bash-scripting

I'm making frequent changes to a bash script and everytime doing "./demo_script.sh" is repetitive.

Is there any way that it can automatically execute as soon as I hit CTRL+ S on keyboard?

Comment: Only after you commented under my answer I realized you probably want something like this: [How to execute a command whenever a file changes](https://superuser.com/q/181517/432690).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do `!./demo_script.sh`, or `!./demo`, or `!./`, or any other shortcut? Or perhaps even `!.`? You should also look at `!!`.

They all look at the contents of the history buffer.

The `!!` just asks the shell to re-execute the last command.

The others asks the shell to execute the last command which starts with those characters given.

The `CTRL-S` is special as it sends the stop signal to the running command, which if you do it to the shell, means it becomes suspended until you release it with `CTRL-Q`.

You will find all `CTRL-<KEY>` are rather special in some way and you really should not interfere with them.

Comment: Ctrl+s does not send any signal. It tells the terminal to stop passing data the command (or anything) wants to write to the terminal. The command may continue, it is unaware, nothing changes *until* it tries to write something. If it tries to write something *then* it will block or notice. And I think even then no signal will be generated.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but not as straightforward as you probably wish.

---

#### Preliminary notes

- You tagged [bash-scripting](/questions/tagged/bash-scripting) and you mentioned "a bash script", but **it's not really clear if your interactive shell is Bash. I *assume* it is.**
- `./demo_script.sh` is a relative path. I will use it for terseness. To be able to run the script regardless of the directory you're in, use `/full/path/to/demo_script.sh` or maybe even `(cd /full/path/to && ./demo_script.sh)` if needed.

---

#### <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> is special

First of all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> is commonly used to stop (pause) the output. [It tells the terminal to stop passing data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137842/108618) the currently running command (or the shell, or anything) wants to write to the terminal. The command may continue, it is unaware, nothing changes until it tries to write something. If it tries to write something then it will block or notice.

If your terminal is configured so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> works this way, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> won't get to whatever program is running. Programs that do want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> may reconfigure the terminal (and probably restore previous settings just before exiting).

Run `stty -a | grep 'stop ='` and you will most likely see (among other things) `stop = ^S;` which means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> works as described above.

Either choose another combination, or tell the terminal not to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. I assume you really want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. This is how you tell the terminal not to capture it:

```
stty stop ''
```

Now you can tell your interactive shell to react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. Keep reading.

---

#### Executing command upon keystroke

To tell an interactive Bash to run `./demo_script.sh` when it reads `^S` from the terminal, invoke this:

```
bind -x '"\C-s":"./demo_script.sh"'
```

This is the simplest way as `bind -x` is designed to run a command. Still it may misbehave. The problem is if you run a command this way then it will find the terminal with settings (imposed by Bash) appropriate for when Bash reads a command. These settings are different than settings appropriate for when Bash runs a command. Bash changes the terminal settings back and forth exactly because settings appropriate for and expected by scripts and commands are not what Bash wants when it shows you the prompt and lets you type and edit a command line.

Your `./demo_script.sh` will find the terminal with unexpected settings. This may result in mishandled (mangled or even missing) terminal output and/or input.

If the script changes the settings of the terminal and doesn't change them back then in turn Bash will find unexpected settings after the script exits.

In other words, in case of a command started from `bind -x` Bash neither configures the terminal for the command, nor it configures the terminal back for itself.

---

#### Generating keystrokes upon keystroke

If the described behavior is a problem, consider the following binding (instead of the above one):

```
bind '"\C-s":"\C-u ./demo_script.sh\C-j"'
```

This will make Bash react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> by

- "typing" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> as if you hit it;

  <sup>(this combination is bound to `unix-line-discard` by default, I assume you did not change it, I used it in case you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> when the command line is not empty;)</sup>
- then "typing"  `./demo_script.sh` as if you typed it;

  <sup>(the leading space will prevent Bash from saving the command to history; remove the space if you wish;)</sup>
- and then "typing" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> as if you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This variant injects keystrokes. Bash will behave as if you *typed* all these, so it will properly configure the terminal for the command and (after the command finishes) again for itself.

Comment: I'll get back to this answer as soon as I try it. Thank You for a very detailed description. I'm using a terminal running on Linux, not sure if Bash/Sh. Also, the shell script is open not in terminal but in a text editor in a separate window. If I hit CTRL+ S there, would it have effect in the terminal?

Comment: @lousycoder My answer is for Bash in a pseudo-terminal or in a terminal emulator. To run the script automatically after you save it in a text editor, you need support from the editor. Or (in case of a GUI text editor) *maybe* your desktop environment can be configured to capture Ctrl+s and to do something (while still passing Ctrl+s to the editor window). But frankly, if you edit in one window and run `./demo_script.sh` (and nothing more) again and again in another window (terminal emulator) then the easiest way is to use a shell with history and to press Up,Enter in the shell each time.